# Spring Integration Flow Logging When No File Found

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-sftp

I already have a working **IntegrationFlow**

```
IntegrationFlows.from(Sftp.inboundAdapter(inboundSftp)
                .localDirectory(this.getlocalDirectory(config.getId()))
                .deleteRemoteFiles(true)
                .autoCreateLocalDirectory(true)
                .filter(new CompositeFileListFilter().addFilter(new LastModifiedLsEntryFileListFilter(config.getRegexFilter())))
                .remoteDirectory(config.getInboundDirectory())
                , e -> e.poller(Pollers.cron(config.getCron())
                        .errorChannel(MessageHeaders.ERROR_CHANNEL).errorHandler((ex) -> {
               }))).publishSubscribeChannel(s -> s
                .subscribe(f -> {
                    ............
                })
                .subscribe(f -> {
                    .......

                })
                .subscribe(f -> f
                        .......
                ))
                .get();
```

I am trying to log when there is no file exists on source directory. I tried to use LastModifiedLsEntryFileListFilter but its fired only when it found a file on server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the question [Spring Integration Flow API does not response when empty remote directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61201149/spring-integration-flow-api-does-not-response-when-empty-remote-directory) comes from another user, it looks like you both talk about the same project and the same problem.

I can't close this your question because there is no vote on my answer over there yet, so I just copy/paste my answer here as well.

The `Sftp.inboundAdapter(inboundSftp)` is a `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` based on a scheduled task according  poller configuration. It really produces nothing into an `outputChannel` if there is no data from the source to build a message. But the point is that a task on trigger is still performed and we have some hooks how to catch that phase.

For this purpose we have an `AbstractMessageSourceAdvice` component for its `afterReceive()` implementation. This is a place where you can perform your "Empty Remote Directory" logic. Such an `Advice` then has to be injected in the `poller(Pollers...advice())`.

See more info in Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.0.M4/reference/html/core.html#conditional-pollers

Comment: I voted on your answer :) You can also use an outbound gateway (LS) to list the remote files.